# usage of speech to text in kivy

Tags: android, python, kivy

How to use pyttsx module in kivy app?

```
import kivy 
import sys
kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.label import Label 
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout 
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput 
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class My(App):
    def build(self):
        return Myapp()

class Myapp(FloatLayout):
    def callback(self,instance):
        import pyttsx
        self.engine=pyttsx.init()
        if self.t1.text:
            self.engine.say("you wrote something")
        self.engine.runAndWait()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Myapp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.t1=TextInput(multiline=True,size_hint_x=0.5, size_hint_y=0.5)
        btn1=Button(text='read',size_hint=(.1,.1),pos_hint= {'x': .5,'top': .2})
        self.add_widget(self.t1)
        self.add_widget(btn1)
        self.bind(on_press=self.callback)

if __name__=='__main__':
    My().run()
```

On clicking the button the callback function is called and it has to speak the text entered in text field.But it doesn't work.Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: must be  developing android app using kivy.

Answer (score 1):

Use the text to speech functions in [plyer](https://github.com/kivy/plyer). These will call the Android api for the task.